# Regular expression for finding the pound sign in the URL in Javascript?

Tags: regex

I'd like to use `location.pathname.match` to find the number that comes after `#` in `some.domain.com/#123` so that I can change some Javascript code from

`res.render('index.ejs' ...`

to

```
var pageNum = location.pathname.match(REGULAR_EXPRESSION_GOES_HERE)[1];
res.render('index' + pageNum + '.ejs' ...
```

So that way, I render `index123.ejs` instead of `index.ejs`.

I've been looking into regular expressions for how to do it and I'm a little lost. Any helpful souls out there have the magic answer?

[EDIT:] You've all been a huge help! I wish I wasn't too new to upvote you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for all this manual stuff. THe location object has the data you want in the `hash` property. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

So, just do:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.length && !isNaN(hash = parseInt(hash.substr(1)))) {
    res.render('index' + hash + '.ejs');
}
else {
    //oops, hash is not a number. Handle it.
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I got the `window.location.hash` to give me `#123`, but the parseInt doesn't seem to be working as intended. But this puts me miles ahead of where I was, so thanks again!

Comment: ah ok - sorry, I though hash would give the string after the pound sign. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = location.pathname.match(/some.domain.com\/\#(.*)$/);
alert(result [1]);
```

And don't forget to check if there *is* result [1]...

Comment: Getting, nothing but null as a result, but thanks for the help either way!

Comment: Well, if you try window.location instead of location.pathname, you could get the result. The way @Roland Bouman did was most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be

```
var pageNum = window.location.hash.replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

If you want to use regex, your code should look like this:

```
var pageNum = location.pathname.match(/#(\d+)/)[1];
```

Check **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hwQkk/)**.